# Doing nmap on a network

Tags: networking, nmap

I used nmap to scan all the ports in the hosts in a network by using the command:

```
$ nmap 172.31.100.0/24
```

What I found is that it showed the following in the result:

> Nmap scan report for 172.31.100.0
>   Host is up (0.0039s latency).
>   Not shown: 998 closed ports
>   PORT   STATE    SERVICE
>   23/tcp open     telnet
>   80/tcp filtered http

What does `172.31.100.0` represent? Is it a specific interface or something else?

Comment: What version of nmap did you use, and what exact command line? Is this the whole report? I don't recognize “scan report” in nmap output. Usually, an address ending in `.0` in a /24 network is the network address and cannot be used for a machine, but it's technically possible to have a machine with this address.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

172.31.100.0 is the IP address of one of the hosts you scanned. If your network is actually 172.31.96.0/21 (or larger), then 100.0 is a perfectly valid IP address.

172.31.100.0 is part of the pre-[CIDR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing) Class B IP space, so you may have gotten a default network of  173.31.0.0/16 if you didn't configure otherwise (and 100.0 completely valid on that network).

If you don't want to scan .0, you can invoke nmap with a range: `nmap -sS 172.31.100.1-254`.